# Non-traditional or Matching in Javascript Regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

Correct me if I'm wrong, but I believe the regular expression ({|}) would traditionally match either a { or a }. But when I have a string like this: "{hello i'm a string}" and I call this function:

```
var album = $(song).data('album').replace(/({|})/, '', 'g');
```

Only the { is replaced, leaving the trailing }. What gives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the non-standard `flags` parameter is ignored if the first argument is a regexp object. According to the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace):

```
To perform a global search and replace, either include the g switch in the 
regular expression or if the first parameter is a string, include g in the 
flags parameter.
```

For your example, the following works:

```
> "{hello}".replace(/({|})/g, '')
> "hello"
```